# SQL Get lowest two values with QUALIFY

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, row-number

I need to get lowest (earliest) 2 Dates after a Test Date based on join to the Test Table.  I've tried running a QUALIFY-ROW_NUMBER-PARTITION, which seemed pretty straight forward in examples but it's not playing nice with my query.  Everything before the QUALIFY works.  I'm not implementing the QUALIFY properly or I should just being using another method.

```
SELECT p.[ENTITY_ID]
,[PROD_DATE]
,[WTR]
,[WCNT]
,[DAYS]
,t.max_TEST_DATE
,wt.TEST_DATE
,wt.TEST_VOL 
FROM (SELECT [ENTITY_ID]
,max([TEST_DATE]) as max_TEST_DATE
FROM [dbo].[PDEN_TEST]
group by ENTITY_ID) as t 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PDEN_WELL_TEST] wt
on t.max_TEST_DATE = wt.TEST_DATE and t.ENTITY_ID = wt.ENTITY_ID
inner join [dbo].[PDEN_PROD] p
on p.ENTITY_ID = t.ENTITY_ID
where PROD_DATE >= TEST_DATE
qualify 
row_number() over (partition by p.ENTITY_ID, [PROD_DATE]) <=2
```

Modified as follows thanks to Gordon but I'm only getting first occurrence of each Entity_ID instead of 2

```
SELECT top (2) with ties p.[ENTITY_ID]
,[PROD_DATE]
,[WTR]
,[WCNT]
,[DAYS]
,t.max_TEST_DATE
,wt.TEST_DATE
,wt.TEST_VOL as IP24
FROM (SELECT [ENTITY_ID]
,max([TEST_DATE]) as max_TEST_DATE
FROM [DI].[dbo].[PDEN_WELL_TEST]
group by ENTITY_ID) as t 
INNER JOIN [DI].[dbo].[PDEN_WELL_TEST] wt
on t.max_TEST_DATE = wt.TEST_DATE and t.ENTITY_ID = wt.ENTITY_ID
inner join [DI].[dbo].[PDEN_PROD] p
on p.ENTITY_ID = t.ENTITY_ID
where PROD_DATE >= TEST_DATE
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (partition BY p.ENTITY_ID ORDER BY PROD_DATE)
```

ENTITY_ID   PROD_DATE   WTR WCNT    DAYS    max_TEST_DATE   TEST_DATE   IP24
60916   1998-12-01  1395    1   31  1998-11-21  1998-11-21  160
60919   1997-11-01  242 1   30  1997-10-10  1997-10-10  9776
60920   1993-04-01  50710   1   30  1993-04-01  1993-04-01  173
60921   1994-07-01  8300    1   14  1994-06-26  1994-06-26  0
60928   2017-04-01  38733   1   30  2017-03-14  2017-03-14  232
60926   2017-06-01  20379   1   20  2017-05-08  2017-05-08  29
60929   2001-07-01  8288    1   31  2001-06-09  2001-06-09  68

Comment: some sample data and expected result please

Comment: I changed the database tag to "teradata".  SQL Server doesn't support qualify (as far as I know).

Comment: As Gordon wrote, there's no QUALIFY in SQL Server, you need to wrap the ROW_NUMBER in a CTE or Dervied Table and move the condition to the outer WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need the `order by` part:

```
qualify row_number() over (partition by p.ENTITY_ID order by PROD_DATE) <= 2
```

If you do need this in SQL Server, you can do:

```
select top (2) with ties . . .
from . . .
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by p.ENTITY_ID order by PROD_DATE)
```

This does the same thing in SQL Server.